# Making a thread wait from main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, wait

i've read a lot of message about making threads wait, but i can't make anything works. I've read the doc about wait, notify, join, lock...but still can't found a way to solve my problem.

I have my main stream and another stream in background (user don't interact with it, it just do his own stuff). In main stream then, user will have the possibility to use some function until he quit the programm. What i want is that, when the user choose to use a function, the stream in background pause during this function, adn then start again after.

I'll explain it with "pseudo" code here:

```java
main(args[]){
    new Thread(new Background(), "Background").start();
    while (user don't quit){
        //user choose a function
        -> find a way to pause Background thread
        chosenFunction();
        -> find a way to unpause the Background thread
    }
}

public class Background implements Runnable{
    public Background(){}
    public void run(){
        while (thread is not paused){
            //do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think i should use join, since i don't want to wait for the completion of another thread but for the completion of a function in another thread. I thought lock was the answer, but i was unable to mke it work. I've tried that:

```java
main(args[]){
    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    new Thread(new Background(lock), "Background").start();
    while (user don't quit){
        //user choose a function
        lock.lock();
        chosenFunction();
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

public class Background implements Runnable{
    private final ReentrantLock lock;
    public Background(ReentrantLock lock){
        this.lock = lock;
    }
    public void run(){
        while (!lock.islocked()){
            //do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Or with:

```java
public void run(){
    while(lock.isLocked){
        sychronized(this){
            wait();
        }
    }
//do some stuff
}
```

But it won't work.

If you need more context: The Thread in Background is waiting for a message from a socket, and the functions the user can call are also using this socket. So yeah, my first thought was to put this socket as synchronized object between the two stream, but i didn't manage to make it work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `volatile` variable. This is a very typical use case of `volatile` variable.

```
public void main() {

    BackgroundServiceThread bst = new BackgroundServiceThread();
    bst.start();

    while (true) {
        //user choose a function
        bst.isPaused = true;
        chosenFunction();
        bst.isPaused = false;
    }
}

private static class BackgroundServiceThread extends Thread {

    volatile boolean isPaused = false;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (!isPaused) {
                //do stuffs;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void chosenFunction() {
    //user choose function
}
```

When you update isPaused in the main thread, the changes is immediately visible in your background service thread because it is volatile.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example:

```
new Thread(new Background(), "Background").start();
while (user don't quit){
    //user choose a function
    -> find a way to pause Background thread
    chosenFunction();
    -> find a way to unpause the Background thread
}
```

The very first problem is: in order to **know** about other objects, you need some sort of handle. Which you don't have here.

Meaning: your code creates a new Thread, and starts that. But the *reference* to that thread is discarded. You can't identify objects unless you **keep** a reference to them. Same goes for your `Background` object.

In other words: when you want multiple threads to communicate with each other, then you need a communication channel between the two sides. For example: an object that **both** thread implementations have access to.

Like (pseudo code here):

```
 Queue<String> commands = ...

 new EnhancedThread(commands).start();
```

The above would start a new thread, and that thread could "listen" on the `commands` queue for, well, commands. So your main thread could then do:

```
 commands.add("COMMAND1");
 commands.add("SUSPEND");
```

and so on.

Repeat: just creating a thread object does nothing. You have to think a *protocol* that can be used to get things done. Thus: focus on the *design* aspects here. Think of your thread(s) as human people. And now ask yourself what exactly you would need to specify for these people to have such kind of interaction.

Your current implementation boils down to "talking to a random guy on the street, to then walk away from him." But how do you expect that the random guy could react to you, after you walked away? You didn't ask for his phone number, so how do you intend to send him messages?

Comment: yeah, that's why i've tried with lock; since i made the lock in main and then gives it to my stream, i have something to handle it. But it didn't worked. That's also why i've tried with a synchronized object, that both my background thread and my main thread use. Didn't work either. I've also tried to make this thread as an extends thread instead of implements runnable, so i could give it a pause method that i'll call in my main thread. Like, everything i could imagine to handle this thread in my mainstream. 
I thought about Queue, but it's rather big for the only option i need.

Comment: The problem is that your code doesn't sync the side and main thread initially! You assume that the main thread does something first, but that won't work all the time. You absolutely need a barrier that ensures that both threads reached the barrier and are in a known good state. Again: you need to first define a clear protocol that does not leave room for ambiguities.